# Regex How to match Empty

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have log structure looks like

```
a b c|
```

so for example:

```
Mozilla 5.0 white|
```

should be matched/extracted to sth like

```
a: Mozilla, b: 5.0, c: white
```

but there is an entry in my log is:

iOS|

which can be explained as

```
a:iOS, b:null, c:null
```

I am using python3 re, doing match with named group ?P

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: "should be matched to sth like [..]" ?! I am completely confused. Can you make one or two concrete examples with the input and the expected matches/matching groups?

Comment: ...and with the regexp you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(?P<a>[^\s]+)(\s+(?P<b>[^\s]+))?(\s+(?P<c>[^\s]+))?\s*\|")

>>> m.groups()
('iOS', None, None)
>>> m.groupdict()
{'c': None, 'a': 'iOS', 'b': None}

>>> m = re.match(r"(?P<a>[^\s]+)(\s+(?P<b>[^\s]+))?(\s+(?P<c>[^\s]+))?\s*\|")

>>> m.groups()
('Mozilla', ' 5.0', ' white')
>>> m.groupdict()
{'c': 'white', 'a': 'Mozilla', 'b': '5.0'}
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that the previous version included spaces in the returned groups - I had factored the \s+ into the (?P<>...) to save a couple bytes, but it had that side effect. So I fixed that and also made it tolerant of spaces before the final '|'

Answer (score 2):

You can put your patterns in a list like following :

```
>>> pattern = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then use `re.findall()` to find all the relative parts, then use `zip` and `dict` to create the relative dictionary:

```
>>> s = "IOS|"
>>> dict(zip(pattern,re.findall('([^\s]+)?\s?([^\s]+)?\s?([^\s]+)?\|',s)[0]))
{'a': 'IOS', 'c': '', 'b': ''}
>>> 
>>> s = "Mozilla 5.0 white|"
>>> 
>>> dict(zip(pattern,re.findall('([^\s]+)?\s?([^\s]+)?\s?([^\s]+)?\|',s)[0]))
{'a': 'Mozilla', 'c': 'white', 'b': '5.0'}
```